# How to target specific attribute with a certain value in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

The problem I am trying to solve is this:

Write the function newMessage, which receives the name of the topic as the parameter. Function should change the background-color of the p tag to red where the data-topic-name is topicName.

For example, if the HTML is:

```
<div>
  <p data-topic-name="discussion">General discussion</p>
  <p data-topic-name="bugs">Bugs</p>
  <p data-topic-name="animals">Animals</p>
</div>
```

After calling newMessage("discussion") the HTML should be:

```
<div>
  <p data-topic-name="discussion" style="background-color: red;">General discussion</p>
  <p data-topic-name="bugs">Bugs</p>
  <p data-topic-name="animals">Animals</p>
</div>
```

Now, I thought I had it when I used the following:

```
function newMessage(topicName) {
  $('p[data-topic-name=topicName]').css('background-color' , 'red')
}
```

unfortunately it does not work.

I thought `p[data-topic-name = topicName]` was the correct selector to use?

Comment: `topicName` in your selector is a string, not the variable you are passing

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track but you need to move the variable name outside of your quotes like:

```
function newMessage(topicName) {
  $('p[data-topic-name='+topicName+']').css('background-color' , 'red')
}
```

Example:

```js
function newMessage(topicName) {
  $('p[data-topic-name='+topicName+']').css('background-color' , 'red')
}
newMessage('discussion');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p data-topic-name="discussion">General discussion</p>
  <p data-topic-name="bugs">Bugs</p>
  <p data-topic-name="animals">Animals</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is the +variableName+ the way variables are passed in jQuery selectors?

Comment: It's the most common way yes