# Create a function that shows text of a selected attribute and value based on function parameters in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the problem I am working on:

An HTML div element contains lists of endangered species grouped by continent and the species population status.

```
<div>
    <ul data-continent="North America">
        <li data-species="California condor">Critically Endangered</li>
        <li data-species="American bison">Near Threatened</li>
    </ul>

    <ul data-continent="Europe">
        <li data-species="Cave bear">Extinct</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Write a function that returns how endangered a species is on a particular continent. For example endangeredSpecies('North America', 'American bison') would return 'Near Threatened'.

Now, I did the following;

```
return $('ul[data-continent="+continent+"]').find('li[data-species="+species+"]').html()
```

Why does this not work? I thought .find would traverse the selected element (in this case traverse the child elements of ul elements with data-continent = continent) and then apply .html() to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string interpolation should look like this

```
return $('ul[data-continent="' + continent + '"]').find('li[data-species="' + species + '"]').html()
```

Comment: Thank you. Though, I am confused since over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57789392/how-to-target-specific-attribute-with-a-certain-value-in-jquery   I simply did $('p[data-topic-name='+topicName+']')  so the variable in between the 2 +, was only enclosed by one set of quotation marks and it worked. But I needed to use two sets of quotations marks for the answer you provided. Why is this?

Comment: Because properly formatted attribute selectors use quotes around the value.  `[attribute="value"]` or `[attribute='value']`.  The choice of inner quote is dictated by what the choice of outer quote was, and is the opposite of it

Comment: This is especially true in your case as the attribute value can have a space in it

Comment: @Tapler exactly!

Comment: As a side note, a template literal is also an option if you do not need IE support

Comment: JoyFulCode is absolutely correct. But for fun, and in addition, you can also do this using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as: ``return $(`ul[data-continent="${continent}"]`).find(`li[data-species="${species}"]`).html();``.

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of jquery's tag find feature.
The best code:

```
function endangeredSpecies(continent, species) { 
  return $("ul[data-continent='"+continent+"']>li[data-species='"+species+"']").text();
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - why is this the "best" code?